# Определение зависимостей (next, prev) для внешних ребер HalfEdge

Tags: алгоритм, dcel, halfedge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно прочитать из stl файла треугольники и заполнить ими структуру half edge (he).
Я так создаю half edge:

1. добавляю в свой he по треугольнику, допустим опосле первой итерации у меня добавляются вершины 1, 2, 9 + ребра 2-1, 1-9, 9-2 ( + для них есть ссыки на предыдущее и следующие ребка) и так до конца.
2. Дальше я ищу соседей для ребер, если они есть, если их нет, то добавляю новые ребра, как, например, для ребра 2-1 будет добавлено новое ребко 1-2(красное).
3. Здесь у меня проблема. Мне нужно установить зависимости prev, next для только что созданных ребер (красных). Как мне правильно понять, что следующие ребро для 3-4  - это 4-5, а не 4-8?

Comment: Вообще говоря никак. Оба варианта с точки зрения HalfEdge правильны. Чтобы выбрать какой-то придётся анализировать координаты - искать минимальный угол.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А если у меня Это 3D объект (что-то типо такого https://ibb.co/3C4RnMr)? можно ли как-то отсортировать отрезки против часовой стрелки?

Comment: Для каждой вершины надо искать плоскость на которую спроектировать грани вокруг вершины. Например, нормаль к этой плоскости может быть средним всех нормалей прилежащих граней. В большинстве разумных ситуаций этого будет достаточно. Но это только эвристика.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, так и пологал, что прийдется так делать, но надеялся на лучшее)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy возможно, есть какой иной вариант?) У меня в задании есть такая подсказка:  `Tip: think about a valency of a vertex.`

Comment: У меня идей нет. Всё что знал сказал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130037/discussion-between-angry-shark-and-stanislav-volodarskiy).